# Multithread server in C++, how to terminate threads and clean up nicely

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, openssl, thread-safety

The server I've written in c++ server works like proxy. Main function:

```
try
{
    Connector c(ip); //establishes persistent connection to the server B
    Listener1 l1(port); //listens incoming connection to the server A (our proxy) and push them into the queue
    Listener2 l2(&c); //listens responses (also push messages) from the server B and push them into the queue
    Proxy p(&c, &l1, &l2); //pulls clients  out from the queue and forwards requests to the server B, pull out everything from the listener2 queue and returns as a responce
    KeepAlive k(&l1, &p); //pushes the empty client to the listeners1's queue thus the proxy sends keepalive to the server B and the response is discarded
    l1.start();
    p.start();
    l2.start();
    k.start();
    l1.join();
    p.join();
    l2.join();
    k.join();
catch(std::string e)
{
    std::cerr << "Error: " << e << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

For now I have problems/doubts as follows:

**1.**I throw an exception from constructors, is it good practise? I throw an exception when it's not possible to establish the connection, that's why the object shouldn't be created I guess.

**2.**There is a problem with closing the application safety and clean up when the connection time-out occurs or the server B closes the connection and so on. listener1 and listener2 use blocking functions (system call accept() and BIO_read from openssl lib) so it's not possible to just set the loop condition from another thread. The problem is also the fact that all the modules are connected and share resources using mutexes. My current piece of code just calls exit function to terminate whole application.

I know this is not a perfect solution, I appreciate any advices and tips.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Constructors should throw exceptions if they fail. C++ is designed to handle that well. Base classes and members are cleaned up if and only if they're already constructed.

Blocking functions from other libraries are always a problem. Windows and POSIX handle it well: `WSAWaitForMultipleObjectEx` and `select` allow you to add an extra handle, which you can use to unblock the wait.

In your `accept` call, you might fake this by creating a connection from the main thread, via localhost. Detecting this "unusual" connection would be a signal to stop accepting further connections.

As for the openSSL read, I'd just close the socket from the main thread, threadsafety be damned. I would make sure that I'd do this quite late in the shutdown, and I wouldn't expect the library to be usable at all after that point.